# JXA: move or duplicate files

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

I’m trying to do a very simple thing — move (or duplicate) a file using JavaScript for Automation introduced with OS X Yosemite.

So far I have something like this.

```
finder = Application("Finder")

finder.move(Path("/Users/user/Source/file.pdf"), {
    to: Path("/Users/user/Destination/file.pdf"),
    replacing: true
})
```

The result is not great.

```
Error -1728: Can't get object.
```

Of course I can just use something like `doShellScript("mv source destination")` but Finder + JAX solution seems to be better.

Answer (score 3):

Finder’s `move` and `duplicate` actions work just fine with JXA `Path` objects. The reason your code fails it that the `to` argument these actions expect is a path to a **folder** while you are providing the path to a **file**. This will work:

```
finder = Application("Finder")

finder.move(Path("/Users/user/Source/file.pdf"), {
    to: Path("/Users/user/Destination/"),
    replacing: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a mess with the JXA and the Finder. I think the problem lies in the Finder loving Aliasses etc. against the nontyped variables in JavaScript. First I thought, the problem was that the target file does not exist and then the `Path()`-call can't return a variable type `file`. But even if you create an empty target file with that name, the script fails (but with another error message...)

The only way I found out was to use the JXA-ObjC-Bridge as descriptor in the JXA release notes:

```
ObjC.import('Cocoa')
error = $()
fMa = $.NSFileManager.defaultManager
fileMoved = fMa.moveItemAtPathToPathError('/Users/user/Source/file.pdf','/Users/user/Destination/file.pdf', error)
if (!fileMoved) {
    $.NSBeep();
    // or do something else depending on error.code
}
```

I think it's a more elegant way than using shell scripting, but that is only a feeling ;-)

Cheers, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Yep, it is a shame. Actually, I got another code to work at least somehow: `Application("Finder").duplicate(Path("/Users/user/Source/file.pdf"))` will create a file named `file copy.pdf`. Another one `Application("Finder").duplicate(Path("/Users/user/Source/file.pdf"), {to: Path("/Users/user/Destination/file.pdf")})` will fail with `Error -1728: Can't get object`. Looks like an issue with the destination path.

Comment: It is: the destination path needs to be a path to a folder, not to a file (`mv` semantics do not apply here). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41086329/990363).

Answer (score -1):

This script works using Finder objects with the move command:

```
var Finder = Application("Finder")
var homeDirectory = Finder.startupDisk.folders["Users"].folders["user"]

var sourceFile = homeDirectory.folders["Source"].files["file.pdf"]
var destinationFolder = homeDirectory.folders["Destination"]

Finder.move(sourceFile, { to: destinationFolder })
```

It also works for the duplicate command.

Comment: Though Finder uses a different path representation model, it can coerce AppleScript aliases and their JXA equivalents, Path objects to that just fine. The issue is OP is providing a path to a file where they should be providing a path to a folder. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41086329/990363).